# react styled components Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to use an svg component as a background image by passing it through as a prop to my css but I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

How can I use an svg component as a background image within styled components?

**CSS**

```
const Div = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: ${props => props.background};
`
```

**app**

```
const App = () => (
  <Div background={<TriangleTrim />}></Div>
)
```

**Svg**

```
export const TriangleTrim = () =>
<svg>
<g>
    <polygon className="triangleTrimSt1" points="9,0 9,0.1 4.5,4.6 0,0.1 0,0    "/>
    <polygon className="triangleTrimSt0" points="9,0.1 4.5,4.6 0,0.1 0,1.5 4.5,6 4.5,6 9,1.5    " />
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it should be done, if you are using WebPack you need to add file-loader for SVG, then you can do

```
import TriangleTrim from './TriangleTrim.svg`

const Div = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(${props => props.background});
`

const App = () => (
  <Div background={TriangleTrim}></Div>
)
```

this will propagate url for this file correctly, you cant specify contents of svg as `background:` in css unless you have base64 data of it or using svg refs.